# Comment of Gauss, on the even integer $x$, in the $p=x^2+y^2$, for primes of the form $p \stackrel{4}{\equiv} 1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, sums-of-squares

$\color{Red}{\text{Question}}$: Let $p \stackrel{4}{\equiv} 1$ be a prime number. 
As you know, there exist natural numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $\color{Blue}{p=x^2+y^2}$; 
$\color{Red}{\text{ where $x$ is even }}$, and $y$ is odd.

Many years ago, I saw a result by **Gauss**, $\color{Red}{\text{ about the even number $x$ }}$ in $\color{Blue}{\text{ the above relation }}$, saying that $x$ satisfies a congruence condition:

$$x \stackrel{f(p)}{\equiv} g(p),$$

where $f(p)$ and $g(p)$ are functions only depending on $p$.

---

---

---

**Edit**: Regarding the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366562/comment-of-gauss-on-the-even-integer-x-or-y-in-the-p-x2y2-for-prim/3458921#3458921) by user "@WhatsUp", it is better for the reader to consider this $\color{Green}{\text{ new question }}$ instead of the $\color{Red}{\text{ previous question}}$:

---

---

---

$\color{Green}{\text{New Question}}$: Let $p \stackrel{4}{\equiv} 1$ be a prime number. 
As you know, there exist **integers** $x$ and $y$ such that $\color{Blue}{p=x^2+y^2}$; 
$\color{Green}{\text{ where $x\stackrel{4}{\equiv} 1$ }}$, and $y$ is even. It is obvious that $x$ is unique. (Also $y$ is unique up to $\pm$ sign.)

Many years ago, I saw a result by **Gauss**, $\color{Green}{\text{ about the number $x\stackrel{4}{\equiv} 1$ }}$ in $\color{Blue}{\text{ the above relation }}$, saying that $x$ satisfies a congruence condition:

$$x \stackrel{f(p)}{\equiv} g(p),$$

where $f(p)$ and $g(p)$ are functions only depending on $p$.

---

---

---

I can not remember what are $f$ and $g$; but I guess that $f(p)=p$, and $g(p)$ was some function containing some factorials. Do anyone has ever seen this statemate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's the following:

> Let $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$ be a prime number, and let $a, b$ be integers such that $a^2 + b^2 = p$ and $a \equiv 1 \mod 4$. Then we have: $$a \equiv \frac{1}{2}\binom{\frac{p - 1}{2}}{\frac{p - 1}{4}}\mod p.$$

This appears in the determination of quartic Gauss sums, as is discussed [in this paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/SDPP_1976-1977__18_2_A8_0.pdf). Note however that the minus sign is an obvious error in that paper.

---

The above is however about the odd number. But the even number is not far: we may assume $b \equiv -\frac{p - 1}{2}!a \mod p$, as in that paper.

More directly, we have $b \equiv -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\frac{p - 1}{2}!}{\frac{p - 1}{4}!}\right)^2 \mod p$. Note however that the $b$ here is not always positive, and hence could be either $x$ or $-x$ in the original question.

Thus we may only get the congruence $x \equiv \pm\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\frac{p - 1}{2}!}{\frac{p - 1}{4}!}\right)^2 \mod p$.

Comment: I'm refering to the equation (15) on page 27-08 in that paper, which is obviously wrong, as can be checked with $p = 5$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. +1

Comment: I EDITED the question to another question, which I think maybe is more useful for the readers! I keep the main question, and I REPLACED " even $x$ " with " $x\stackrel{4}{\equiv} 1$ " in the next question!

Comment: Right, that way we get a nicer congruence relation without the $\pm$ sign.